# How to get RESX value from other project in the same solution

Tags: asp.net

I have two projects in the same solution:

```
 My.Solution.name.with.dots
   BLL
   Web
```

in the BLL project, I create a class that need to get a global resx value from RESX file that is placed in the Web project. Is it possible ?

BLL can't have a reference to Web project because of the project dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource, as an accessible class, is part of your web dll. I would be better to move your resource to a separate project that both libraries can access.

Alternatively have a play with the [ResXReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader.aspx) to read a resource file from a specific location.

Comment: hm but the compiler doesn't see the ResXResourceReader even if I type "using System.Resources;". When I want to add a reference to my project I don't see the System.Resources in the .NET tab. I user .net 3.5 and the project is a Class Library

Comment: Yep, it's a bit of a pain, you have to reference System.Windows.Forms - odd for a web project!